# How to launch default Web browser and go to Home page using ShellExecute with http: URI scheme?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shellexecute

We can use ShellExecute to launch default Web browser and go to specified web page with http: URI scheme. But how can we launch default Web browser and go to Home page using ShellExecute?

I can get some information from here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/224816  and  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt228340.aspx#browser    but I still don't know how to go Home page. Very appreciate if you can provide some information

Comment: Technically, there's no reason why a browser needs a Home Page, you increasingly see a mosaic screen used instead.

Answer (score 2):

What is the default browser on Windows? Is it the registered handler of the HTTP protocol? Is it the default client registered under [`Clients\StartMenuInternet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd203067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

If we assume that [the HTTP handler is the default browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb757032) then you can use [`AssocQueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471(v=vs.85).aspx) to get information about the registration:

```
WCHAR szBrowser[MAX_PATH];
DWORD cch = MAX_PATH;
AssocQueryString(ASSOCF_NOTRUNCATE, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, L"http", NULL, szBrowser, &cch);
```

As a side note, just getting the executable might not be the best option, the user could have configured it with parameters like `--some-browser-option --profile c:\foo` and those would be ignored. `ASSOCSTR_COMMAND` can retrieve the command but you need to replace %1 with a empty string.

Even if you do all of this it can still break in certain configurations. A protocol registration is not required to specify a executable, it is legal to just have a [COM object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378382(v=vs.85).aspx). I would therefore recommend that you read the StartMenuInternet client as a fallback.

I don't think there is a standard parameter to open the homepage (unlike `?` for search), you just have to hope that starting the browser without a URL will open the homepage(s).

Comment: @JonathanPotter `"c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http://` does not, nor does `start http://`. The both show a invalid address page in IE.